# Работа с прокси PHP

Tags: прокси, php, proxy

Делаю чекер аккаунтов ВКонтакте (ВЕБ версию). открываю страницу при помощи curl (эмитирую андроид)
Но вот проблема - не могу никак сделать, чтобы открывалось через прокси.

```
// Ф-я отправки запроса
    function send($link, $params = "", $useragent = "VKAndroidApp/3.0.1-10 (Android 4.0.4; SDK 13; armeabi-v7a; HTC Supersonic; ru)") {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        if ($params != "") {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Код curl запроса предоставьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_address);
```

Comment: Естественно, что `$proxy_address` должен содержать реальный адрес работающего прокси ;-)